# How can I add questions about demographics once in Crowdflower?

Tags: crowdflower

Hi,

I am creating a Crowdflower task but I am having some problems.

Contributors need to describe the image that they see with one or two words. I also need additional information, such as gender, age and education. I added these questions but these comes with every displayed image. So the contributor needs to answer this 10 times, but he/she only needs to answer this once. How can I change this?

Thanks! Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Yukie,Stackoverflow is handling code problems, you should try one of the other Q&A sites.

Comment: Thanks, I thought this could be programmed into the code of Crowdflower. But I can't figure it out ...

Answer (score 1):

After trying a lot, I couldn't find a better solution than asking the contributor for the demographic data once per assignment and give him/her the option to skip the form if already filled.

The code for this looks as follows:

**CML**

```xml
<cml:group class="demographics" label="Demographics">
  <p>Please give us some demographic background of you.</p>
  <cml:checkbox label="I already submitted this data successfully" name="demographics_filled" />
  <cml:group only-if="!demographics_filled">
    <!-- TODO: Costomize the content of this groups as needed -->
    <!-- Don't include these questions in the test questions! -->
    <cml:text label="Mother tongue" gold="false" validates="required"></cml:text>
    <cml:radios label="Gender" gold="false" validates="required">
      <cml:radio label="Male" value="male"></cml:radio>
      <cml:radio label="Female" value="female"></cml:radio>
    </cml:radios>
  </cml:group>
  <hr />
</cml:group>

<!-- TODO: here goes the actual task -->
<cml:text label="Enter {{id}}:" validates="required"></cml:text>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
require( [ "jquery-noconflict" ], function($) {
  $('.demographics').hide();
  $('.demographics').first().show();
});
```